# Subclass of UIViewController don't catch touch event

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a parent class (A) that is UIViewController. Than i create class B that is subclass of class A. What happens is that i can't catch touch events in class B with methods like touchesBegan. But if i implement this methods in class A ... they get called.

```
@interface A:UIViewController
.....

@interface B:A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement those methods in your `UIView` subclasses, not in `UIViewController` subclasses.

Comment: Hmmm ... i think i don't get it. I added some more info in my question.

Comment: Everything works now. It was my mistake. I had some sort of bug. My subclassing works:) Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 7):

To use a UIViewController, must do event like:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch;
    CGPoint pos;

    for( touch in touches )
    {
        //pos = [ touch locationInView:self ]; // Only work on UIView
        pos = [touch locationInView:self.view ];       // Work on UIViewController

        //NSLog(@"Touch: %f, %f",pos.x,pos.y);

        // Send X, Y, tapcount
        _faceOff->toucheBegan( pos.x, pos.y, [ [ touches anyObject ] tapCount ]);
    }
}
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to subclass UIView to implement the method touchesBegan.

```
@interface YourCustomView : UIView

@implementation YourCustomView

// Override this function to get the touch
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"TOUCH!");
}
```

And now set the view of your VC as a "YourCustomView"

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController
{
     YourCustomView*    view  
}
```

Comment: Yes, ok, but this changes the architecture. Is there really nothing i can do? Maybe link or enable something.

Comment: I had the same problem recently and it changes only little in the architecture.

Comment: Everything works now. It was my mistake. I had some sort of bug. My subclassing works:) Thanks for answer!